# What's the command line for rrdtool to create a graph using the last update time as the end time?

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

Going off of this question: [Print time of recording for LAST value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237506/print-time-of-recording-for-last-value)

It appears possible to have rrdtool compute the timestamp of the last update in a rrd.  How do you use this in a command as the "end" time?

i.e. I want to do something like this:

```
rrdtool graph img.png -a PNG -s e-600 -e LASTUPDATETIME -v "CPU Usage" \
  --title "CPU Utilization" DEF:ds0a=node.rrd:ds0:AVERAGE \  
  DEF:ds1a=node.rrd:ds1:AVERAGE AREA:ds0a#35b73d:"User" \
  LINE1:ds1a#0400ff:"System"
```

I tried mucking about the DEF, CDEF and VDEF things to no avail:

```
rrdtool graph img.png -a PNG -v "CPU Usage" --title "CPU Utilization" \
  DEF:data=node.rrd:x:AVERAGE CDEF:count=data,UN,UNKN,COUNT,IF  \
  VDEF:last=count,MAXIMUM \
  DEF:ds0a=node.rrd:ds0:AVERAGE:start=end-600:end=last \
  DEF:ds1a=node.rrd:ds1:AVERAGE:start=end-600:end=last \
  AREA:ds0a#35b73d:"User" LINE1:ds1a#0400ff:"System"
```

This results in:

```
ERROR: end time: unparsable time: last
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the command line, you could do

```
rrdtool graph img.png -a PNG -s e-600 -e `date +%s node.rrd` -v "CPU Usage" \
  --title "CPU Utilization" DEF:ds0a=node.rrd:ds0:AVERAGE \  
  DEF:ds1a=node.rrd:ds1:AVERAGE AREA:ds0a#35b73d:User \
  LINE1:ds1a#0400ff:System
```

Comment: Minor flaw in the command line, there needs to be a -r for the date command, but otherwise it works fine!  Thanks very much!  (`date +%s -r node.rrd`)